# A/V receiver that can increase the level of LFE channel mixed into front left and right channels output in case when no subwoofer is used

Tags: audio, sound-system

In the few A/V receivers I have used, if they are configured not to use the subwoofer, the LFE (.1) channel is mixed into the front left, right speakers. There is an option in the menu to decrease the LFE level, but there is no way of increasing it. The default value is 0 db and you can only go down.

So, are there any A/V receivers that let you increase this LFE level in case you decide you want to hear more LFE in your setup without subwoofer, than the receiver calibrates by default.

Comment: This is far too broad [& also off-topic]. There are many that will try to auto-compensate & there are many you can turn all the other channels down independently. Anything with Audessy will set up the entire system on its own.

Comment: Yes, audyssey sets everything up. In case of a setup that has a physical subwoofer it would be easy to adjust the subwoofer volume separately both ways (though, if any speakers are set to small, we also control the level of bass from these small speakers' channels, not only LFE). But when there's no subwoofer, the LFE is mixed into L/R channels, so turning L/R channels volume down also turns down the audible LFE volume. We can adjust the LFE level in settings, but only down. So I'm looking for a receiver that would allow to turn up this LFE channel, if there are any.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think this is off-topic since receivers do interface with a computer and he is asking for a receiver that does something specific extra (with like built in EQ to make the base more loud if I'm correct). Maybe we don't know an easy answer but it technically isn't off-topic

Comment: thank you Irsu85, this feature that I'm looking for is more like channel mixer than EQ. I want to increase the LFE channel level, that is mixed into L/R channels. Or decrease all other channel levels, except LFE, but the level adjustment has to be done before the LFE is mixed into L/R, not after (not the level of outputted channel level after the mix of LFE to L/R is already done), I don't know how to express this more clearly for others to understand.. :)

Comment: I don't see anything on meta re A/V but I think we're on a slippery slope if we go down that path. There are many sites with far greater in-depth analysis/recommendation for all things A/V & HTPC. If this was being pre-mixed in a computer, then such as the realtek CP can do it. Once outside the computer, I think we're beyond the purview for this stack.

Comment: I see, if this stack must be purely PC related, then I guess my question might be considered off topic (though A/V receivers have some kind of computers/processors in them). I guess there aren't any StackExchange sites that are more suited for questions about consumer A/V equipment? I really like the StackExchange sites and getting info on them.

Comment: I've raised this on meta requesting clarification - https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/774/clarification-on-audio-visual-hardware-recommendations - I'm not in charge, I don't make policy ;) I don't even have much rep on this particular stack - not enough yet to even vote to close; but network-wide I'm fairly well-established [which *still* doesn't make me in charge of anything;) So I thought best to open it up for discussion.